# Swift Firebase: Appropriate place to reloadData()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to `reloadData()` after fetching data in an async operation from Firebase. I am having difficulty finding the appropriate location to do the `reloadData()` as at different location, it either refreshes one section of the tableView and not the other, or it does not refresh at all, or worse, the refresh jumbles up the dataset.

Here is my code so far, and a description of the outcome when I `reloadData()` at that particular location:

```
func getData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.titleView.setTitle(viewController: self, animate: true, title: "Updating...")
    }

    ref.child("conversations").child(userUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let snapDatasnapshot = snap as! DataSnapshot
            let snapValues = snapDatasnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let recipientUID = snapDatasnapshot.key

            for (key, value) in snapValues {
                let conversationStartTime = value["conversationStartTime"] as! Double

                if calculateMinutesLeft(conversationStartTime) >= 0 {
                    let messagesDatasnapshot = snapDatasnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: shoutoutID).childSnapshot(forPath: "messages")
                    let messagesArray = messagesDatasnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.startTimeDictionary[shoutoutID] = conversation

                    for message in messagesArray {
                        let messageID = message.key
                        self.ref.child("messages").child(messageID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (messagesSnapshot) in
                            let dictionary = messagesSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                            let timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as! Double
                            let readReceipt = dictionary["readReceipt"] as! Bool

                            if let messageText = dictionary["message"] {
                                let message = messageText as! String
                                let m = Message(fromUserUID: self.userUID, message: message, timestamp: timestamp, recipientUserUID: recipientUID, imageUrl: nil, readReceipt: readReceipt)
                                self.messagesDictionary[conversation] = m
                                self.messages = Array(self.messagesDictionary.values)
                            } 
                            //Location 1
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                self.titleView.setTitle(viewController: self, animate: false, title: "Chats")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    //Expired Convos
                    self.expiredConversations.append(conversation)

                    //Location 2
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                       self.titleView.setTitle(viewController: self, animate: false, title: "Chats")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if self.messages.isEmpty && self.expiredConversations.isEmpty {
            self.titleView.setTitle(viewController: self, animate: false, title: "Chats")
        }

        //Location 3
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.titleView.setTitle(viewController: self, animate: false, title: "Chats")
        }
    }
    //Location 4
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.titleView.setTitle(viewController: self, animate: false, title: "Chats")
    }
}
```

The `messages` will be displayed in section 0 of the tableView while `expiredConversations` will be displayed in section 1 of the tableView.

My current implementation is at location 1 and 2. Doing so correctly reloads both sections of the table but will tend to jumble the data up when refreshed multiple times, or when tableView size gets too large. Otherwise:

- At location 1 only, will refresh just section 0
- At location 2 only, will refresh just section 1
- At location 3 and 4, will refresh all sections, but give empty `messages` and `expiredConversations`

Any advice where is the best or ideal location to `reloadData()`? Or could my implementation be wrong totally?

EDIT: tableViewDelegate and tableViewDatasource

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        if messages.isEmpty {
            return 1
        } else {
            return messages.count
        }
    case 1:
        return expiredConversations.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if messages.isEmpty {
            let noConversationsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "noConversationsCell", for: indexPath) as! NoActiveConversationsTableViewCell
            noConversationsCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            return noConversationsCell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatLogTableViewCell
            let message = messages[indexPath.row]
            let conversation = conversations[indexPath.row]
            //All the data model thing to populate the cells
            return cell
        }

    case 1:
        let expiredConversationsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expiredConversationsCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpiredConversationsTableViewCell
        let conversation = expiredConversations[indexPath.row]
        //All the data model thing to populate the cells

        return expiredConversationsCell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: Location 1 should be the best place to reload the tableView. Just everytime you add a new data to your data source, that's when you'd want to reload your view. If you could upload a sample project, I'd be happy to check it out. OR perhaps it would really help us if you could show us your tableViewDatasource and delegate functions.

Comment: @Glenn location 1 only refresh section 0 of the tableView. Section 1 will remain unpopulated unless location 2 is included too. However if I include both location 1 and 2, the reloadData() will jumble the data up when I scroll up and down. Also I've included the datasource and delegate functions

Comment: It should be easy to debug this. Is this a production-level project? If not, perhaps you could share your repo or perhaps a clone of it. But before that, are you returning `2` to `numberOfSections` dataSource method?

Comment: @Glenn its a production project and yes I return `2` to `numberOfSections`